# Нужно ли вычищать результат запроса если он в цикле?

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть скрипт на PHP в котором используется `mysqli`.
В цикле выполняется n запросов к БД.

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('host','username','pass','dbname');

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  $data = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Booking WHERE route_id ='.$i);
  echo mysqli_fetch_row($data)[0];
}
```

Вопрос: нужно ли вызывать `mysqli_free_result($data)` в каждой итерации цикла или память сама очищается после каждой итерации?

Comment: а зачем здесь цикл? Что мешает получить результат сразу по всем id? Т.е. `...WHERE route_id  IN (...) GROUP BY route_id`

Comment: Этот запрос просто для примера. Вопрос именно про очищение памяти после запроса в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужно.
Поскольку ты перезаписываешь переменную, ты перезаписываешь и все данные, ассоциированные с ней в памяти.

Comment: А после выхода из цикла, переменная объявленная внутри уничтожается, так ведь?

Comment: @atom-22 нет, переменнаяи сама не уничтожается